# what figure of speech/ literary device is the following?

Tags: figures-of-speech

When something is implied but we still state it to reinforce the idea, I suspect it might be tautology but isn't tautology repetition of idea in different form ? implication is not required in tautology I think

> free gift
>
> cold winter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might be looking for ***pleonasm***, rather than tautology.

According to Collins ***[pleonasm](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pleonasm)*** :

> ***noun*** (rhetoric)
>
> 1)  the use of more words than necessary or an instance of this, such as a tiny little child

Also according to Collins, ***[tautology](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tautology)*** :

> ***noun*** (plural) -gies
>
> 1) the use of words that merely repeat elements of the meaning already conveyed, as in the sentence Will these supplies be adequate enough? in place of Will these supplies be adequate

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for